# Can I access IIdentity from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm adding some Web API services to an existing MVC application.  I have a model binder for my MVC controllers to get the user object stored in a CustomIdentity.  I'm trying to reproduce this for my Web API actions.

In the MVC Controller or its binders I can use

```
controllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity
```

The ApiController doesn't have the HttpContext object.  Is there anyway to access the IIdentity object from the Web API?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

They removed GetUserPrincipal in ASP.NET MVC 4 RC. However it seems the ApiController property **User** has replaced this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user

Comment: But how do you access User (which is a property of the controller) in your `IsAuthorized` method?

Comment: If you mean the `AuthorizationAttribute.IsAuthorized` method, you can use `principal.Identity`.

Comment: ...and where would one get `principal` from?

Comment: See msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.authorizationattribute.isauthorized%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Answer (score 30):

Yes you can. `ApiController` has a `Request` property of type `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`; this holds details about the current request naturally (it also has a setter for unit testing purposes). `HttpRequestMessage` has a `Properties` dictionary; you will find the value of the key `MS_UserPrincipal` holds your `IPrincipal` object.

In researching this answer, I came across the `System.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions` which has a `GetUserPrincipal(this HttpRequestMessage request)` extension method which accesses this dictionary value; I hadn't seen this extension method before and was accessing `Request.Properties["MS_UserPrincipal"]` directly, but this might be a better method (less dependent on the ASP.NET Web Api team keeping the name of the key the same...)

Comment: Thank you! I probably would have wasted a lot of time looking for this  rather obscure extension method in the object browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this [extension method](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpRequestMessageExtensionMethods.cs) from System.ServiceModel.dll:

```
public static IPrincipal GetUserPrincipal(this HttpRequestMessage request);
```

as:

```
IPrincipal principal = request.GetUserPrincipal();
IIdentity identity = principal.Identity;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found this way.
In your ApiController you can use
`base.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.;`