# Is it possible to set an instance variable or pass data to a controller from a custom authorize attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have an authorize attribute that extends System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and overrides the onAuthorization method.  It queries the DB with a token that comes from the request to see if the session is valid.  From that, it knows the associated userId.  I would like to somehow make the userId available to the controller of the action being called.  Somehow setting an instance variable would be ideal because I want to unit test the controller.  Perhaps that is not possible or there is a better way to go about doing it.  Please let me know.  I am using ApiController.

Thanks

Comment: You are not supposed to have any kind of session controls since REST is stateless by design.
Anyhoo... this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505526/asp-net-owin-identity-how-to-get-userid-from-a-web-api-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the appropriate way to handle this situation, but to answer my question, one can use actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.  From there I can call a setter or set a public instance variable  Please let me know if this a bad approach.  Regarding sessions with REST, I am not too concerned with having a pure REST implementation.