# Problems with integrating DB with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

i am building a ticketing system which customers can add new tickets to the system and employees can help them with there requests. I built the data base with an ADO file and my question is, is it possible to use the identity user and all of the database that comes with the mvc5 web application yet add additional tables with connections. i have been trying to do this for a while with no success.
!(http://postimg.org/image/v49eh3gql/) this is my database and i would like to extend application user and use my other attributes as well as my other tables and the roles table that comes with mvc all in one database.
any help would be appreciated 
cheers :)

Comment: Do you mean EDM file?

Comment: actually i meant ADO the file is a EDMX

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same database but I think its better to keep them apart. Add the properties for your user entity to `IdentityModels.Cs` and to the `AccountViewModels.cs` where appropriate. Since the views for these viewmodels are already created you have to add the attributes to the view yourself. Then in the package manager console **Enable-Migrations** Copy and paste the command that has the applicationDbConted in it. **Add-Migration -Init** then run **Update-Database**

[Here is a post about how to access the logged in user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505526/asp-net-owin-identity-how-to-get-userid-from-a-web-api-controller)

`is it possible to use the identity user and all of the database that comes with the mvc5 web application yet add additional tables with connections.`

*In other words, can you have an application with database first and model first?* 
Yes, but you have to be careful that you don't migrate the database first dbcontext.