# Get the current user, within an ApiController action, without passing the userID as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

How do we get the current user, within an secure ApiController action, without passing the userName or userId as a parameter?

We assume that this is available, because we are within a secure action. Being in a secure action means that the user has already authenticated and the request has her bearer token. Given that WebApi has authorized the user, there may be a built in way to access the userId, without having to pass it as an action parameter.

Comment: Please, see this Answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26453782/3290276
Add the claim did the trick

Answer (score 162, accepted):

In WebApi 2 you can use `RequestContext.Principal` from within a method on ApiController

Comment: We don't have that property, it seems. Hmm. Maybe we are using an old version of WebApi.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Ok, so if you are using Web API 1 then you I believe there is a Prinicpal property on ApiController.  This is just a fancy wrapper around accessing the Request.Properties collection.  The principal object is stored in that dictionary.

Comment: Thank God for this answer.  Been spending the last 2 hours trying to find where the new identity property was for the context.

Comment: Just don't forget `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

Comment: @Overlord Or any other piece of middleware that sets the appropriate value in the request.Properties dictionary.

Comment: which current user would it be? the user under which the Web API services are running?

Comment: @DarrelMiller is there a way to get the same (say request context) from other parts of the code (not within controller).

Comment: @AjayAradhya Only if you pass it there.  Previous efforts on web frameworks have shown that using static properties to access request context causes all kinds of architectural problems.  It's convenient at first but it causes soooooo much pain long term.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I was wondering all over the web trying to find a static ancestor for web api calls. You saved my day. Will pass it as parameter wherever required :)

Comment: If you are not able to find the property then its possible that you are using the static Class RequestContext, the RequestContext.Principal property is on the filterContext parameter when you override the AuthorizeAttribute. e.g.; filterContext.RequestContext.Principal

Answer (score 45):

You can also access the principal using the [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user.aspx) property on [`ApiController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.aspx).

So the following two statements are basically the same:

```
string id;
id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
id = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: I am trying to use what you've written here but the GetUserId() function always returns null. The user is auth'd, I'm passing a bearer token, and the ApiController has the [Authorize] header

Comment: The GetUserId() function returns an ID only if the user has a NameIdentifier claim. For an example of how to resolve this, refer to Oswaldo's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505526

Answer (score 17):

Hint lies in Webapi2 auto generated account controller

Have this property with getter defined as

```
public string UserIdentity
        {
            get
            {
                var user = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
                return user;//user.Email
            }
        }
```

and in order to get UserManager - In WebApi2 -do as Romans (read as AccountController) do

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); }
        }
```

This should be compatible in IIS and self host mode

Answer (score 12):

None of the suggestions above worked for me. The following did!

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

I guess there's a wide variety of scenarios and this one worked for me. My scenario involved an AngularJS frontend and a Web API 2 backend application, both running under IIS. I had to set **both** applications to run **exclusively** under Windows Authentication.

No need to pass any user information. The browser and IIS exchange the logged on user credentials and the Web API has access to the user credentials on demand (from IIS I presume).

Comment: Note, HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity returns WindowsIdentity.

Answer (score 8):

Karan Bhandari's answer is good, but the AccountController added in a project is very likely a `Mvc.Controller`.  To convert his answer for use in an ApiController change `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()` to `Request.GetOwinContext()` and make sure you have added the following 2 `using` statements:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

Answer (score 8):

In .Net Core use `User.Identity.Name` to get the Name claim of the user.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` gets the value of the [name](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name) claim. It's not Active Directory-specific.

Comment: @Nate Thanks for your comment, I've fixed it

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Asp.Identity UseManager, it automatically sets the value of

> RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId()

based on **IdentityUser** you use in creating the **IdentityDbContext**.

If ever you are implementing a custom user table and owin token bearer authentication, kindly check on my answer.

[How to get user context during Web Api calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657852/how-to-get-user-context-during-web-api-calls/39262408#39262408)

Hope it still helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string userName;
string userId;
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null 
        && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != null)
{
    userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
}
```

Or based on Darrel Miller's comment, maybe use this to retrieve the HttpContext first.

```
// get httpContext
object httpContext;
actionContext.Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out httpContext);
```

See also:

[How to access HTTPContext from within your Web API action](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/02/28/how-to-access-httpcontext-from-within-your-web-api-action.aspx)

Comment: Don't use HttpContext as it limits your hosting options and makes your code hard to test.

Comment: The HttpContext object will not be in the dictionary if you are Self-host, or OwinHttpListener hosted