# How to reopen SignalR connection by connection id on page refresh?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

If I store a connection id associated with an order in my DB, can I use that connection id to reopen the same SignalR connection when the page is refreshed.

Is there a way to specify a connection id to open when calling `$.connection.hub.start()` ?

Something like `$.connection.hub.start("001ddf34-23sd-nds7d-asdjh-647hfash3")`

Comment: Why do you store the connection ID? Why not the user?

Comment: @mason thank you for reaching out. It's my first time using SignalR. How can I get the user so that I can store it (I take it you're referring to a user piece of the connection context and not my customer entity)? And is it possible to reopen a connection to that user like I am wishing to do with a connection id? I will google these things now but if you know the syntax to get the user or open a connection to that user, please post it.

Comment: The way I've seen it implemented is that you talk to a user via `Clients.User(userId).doSomething()`. This will call `doSomething` on all clients that are connected with that `userId`.

Comment: When a page closes/refreshes the client stops the connection and the server no longer keeps track of the client. To connect to the server you need to start a connection and during this process the server assigns a new connection id to the client. Instead of trying to circumvent this you could pass some additional parameter to the server to correlate the same client across multiple connection ids.

Comment: @mason Thanks again. Do you know of a way to get the userId from the client? Previously, I was using `$.connection.hub.id` to get the connection id from javascript.

Comment: I think you really should just forget about the connection ID's. In your hub, have a look at `Context.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: @mason will do. I'm going to try to use the user id as you suggested. However my context does not have a `.User` property so `Context.User.Identity.Name` throws an error. I must be missing something. Any ideas? Thank you very much for your patience. I am currently trying `var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyAppHub>();
string name = hubContext.User.Identity.Name;
hubContext.Clients.User(name).send("Test Message");`

Comment: In that case, you're not *within* the hub. You're just getting the context of the hub. Where are you when you call that? An MVC controller? A background process? A Web Forms code behind?

Comment: @mason I'm in an Api controller. When you say within the hub, do you mean in the MyAppHub class itself? Thanks

Comment: Yes, when I say within the hub, I mean within an instance method of the hub class. But assuming your UserId's in Web API lined up with the UserId's in SignalR, you can [get your current username from Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616951/get-the-current-user-within-an-apicontroller-action-without-passing-the-userid) and use that. And if the users aren't matching up, see [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Comment: @mason Ok that makes sense. The user's are not matching up (id and username from `RequestContext.Principal` are empty). I will try to follow the instructions on the guide you linked me to for mapping them tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: @mason I would like to map connections to orders, not users. Think I could map orderId's to the request user id the same way your link maps custom user names?

Comment: Your order table should already have a relationship to a user, right? So I really see it as you just need to make sure SignalR has the same UserId or a way to go from the SignalR UserId to the Order UserId.