# c# repository pattern how to access values from a dependency injected class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a c# aspnet mvc (not core) project where Im using repository pattern and dependency injection (ninject).

This is a sample of a controller:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    ISecurityRepository _securityRepo = default(ISecurityRepository);
    AppState _appState;

    public MainController(ISecurityRepository securityRepo)
    {
        _securityRepo = securityRepo;
        _appState = (AppState)Session["appstate"];
    }

    public ActionResult Employee(int employeeId)
    {
        var permissions = _securityRepo.GetEmployeePermissions(
            employeeId,
            _appState.userId,
            _appState.sessionId);

        return View(permissions);
    }

    public ActionResult Leave(int leaveId, int employeeId)
    {
        var permissions = _securityRepo.GetEmployeeLeavePermissions(
                leaveId,
                employeeId,
                _appState.userId,
                _appState.sessionId);

        return View(permissions);
    }

    public ActionResult Holiday(int holidayId, int employeeId)
    {
        var permissions = _securityRepo.GetEmployeeHolidayPermissions(
            holidayId,
            employeeId,
            _appState.userId,
            _appState.sessionId);

        return View(permissions);
    }
}
```

`ISecurityRepository` is being injected and thats working perfect, but what I want to do is like to get in my `SecurityRepository` the `_appState` class values without the need to pass into every method `userId` and `companyId` every time.

This is my `SecurityRepository.cs`

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public EmployeePermissions GetEmployeePermissions(int employeeId, int userId, int sessionId)
    {
        // ... some code here
        return employeePermissions;
    }

    public EmployeeLeavePermissions GetEmployeeLeavePermissions(int leaveId, int employeeId, int userId, int sessionId)
    {
        // ... some code here
        return employeeLeavePermissions;
    }

    public EmployeeHolidayPermissions GetEmployeeHolidayPermissions(int holidayId, int employeeId, int userId, int sessionId)
    {
        // ... some code here
        return employeeHolidayPermissions;
    }

    // ... some more methods

}
```

What I would like to do is to have something like this:

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    // here have maybe a constructor that receives the AppState variable from MainController, or a public property

    public EmployeePermissions GetEmployeePermissions(int employeeId)
    {
        // a way that I can user _appState here!!
        return employeePermissions;
    }
}
```

The injection is done inside `NinjectWebCommon` class

```
/// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind(typeof(ISecurityRepository)).To(typeof(Data.SecurityRepository));


        }
```

Any advice or sample code that I can follow?

Comment: how do you register your repository within a ninject? are you on `asp.net` or on `asp.net core`?

Comment: asp.net (not core) and inside NinjectWebCommon.cs I have in the RegisterService method:

  kernel.Bind(typeof(ISecurityRepository)).To(typeof(Data.SecurityRepository));

Comment: Please edit you question and paste you code there. So, you just need to somehow pass value from session to you repository?

Comment: I need to pass not only session, maybe other information but that could live in AppState object. Let me edit and show how the injection is done in NinjectWebCommon.

Comment: Create a factory that will receive your _appState and return the repositiry initialized with _appState. Then inject factory instead repositiry.

Comment: Do you have a sample of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just need to somehow pass value from session to you repository. Actually there is a lot of ways to achive this.

One way would be a some-kind-of `Initialize` method in your repository class (and in your repository interface, ofcourse):

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public void Initialize(AppState appState)
    {
        _userId = appState.userId;
        _sessionId = appState.sessionId;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

Then you may call it in your controller constructor:

```
public MainController(ISecurityRepository securityRepo)
{
    _securityRepo = securityRepo;
    _securityRepo.Initialize(Session["appstate"] as AppState);
}
```

---

Another way - you can handle setting your dependency in the [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). Just add some kind of accessor:

```
public class AppStateAccessor
{
    public AppState AppState { get; set; }
}
```

Then set it in your filter:

```
public class RequestScopeDependencySetupFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public RequestScopeDependencySetupFilter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var accessor = _kernel.Get<AppStateAccessor>();
        accessor.AppState = context.HttpContext.Session["appstate"] as AppState;
    }
}
```

Then register this filter as global:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    var kernel = /* get your IKernel somehow */
    filters.Add(new RequestScopeDependencySetupFilter(kernel));
}
```

And finally use it in your repository:

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public SecurityRepository(AppStateAccessor accessor)
    {
        _userId = accessor.AppState.userId;
        _sessionId = accessor.AppState.sessionId;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

Just don't forget to bind your dependencies right. The key point of this method is that your `AppStateAccessor` instance **is transient** and live in **request scope**. Ninject (specificly `Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation` extension) allows you to bind instance of object in DI container for a request scope:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    // bind AppStateAccessor in request scope
    kernel.Bind<AppStateAccessor>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    // transient repository
    kernel.Bind<ISecurityRepository>().To<Data.SecurityRepository>();

    // other dependencies...

}
```

---

And one more way. Just use `HttpContext.Current` static property in your repository:

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public SecurityRepository()
    {
        var appState = HttpContext.Current.Session["appstate"] as AppState;

        _userId = appState.userId;
        _sessionId = appState.sessionId;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

Easy to implement, but add a hard static dependency to your repository - forget about unit testing.

---

Just one more way (which is a combination of 2nd and 3rd, thanks @Nkosi) simular to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886836/how-to-access-user-in-a-service-context-in-web-api/45908900#45908900). Extract interface from `AppStateAccessor`:

```
public interface IAppStateAccessor
{
    AppState AppState { get; }
}
```

Then change `AppStateAccessor` a bit:

```
public class AppStateAccessor
{
    public AppState AppState { get; }
        = HttpContext.Current.Session["appstate"] as AppState;
}
```

Then use this interface in your repository:

```
public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public SecurityRepository(IAppStateAccessor accessor)
    {
        _userId = accessor.AppState.userId;
        _sessionId = accessor.AppState.sessionId;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

This time your service is fully decoupled from `HttpContext` and can be easily unit-tested.

Comment: @vasily.sib Go with the same accessor design but instead of having to use a filter, have the accessor implementation wrap the static context. Simplifies the design and still decouples the context.

Comment: @Nkosi how is that done? Thanks a lot also @vasily.sib?

Comment: @VAAA To avoid taking away from the already provided answer, check a similar answer I gave here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908900/5233410 Instead of the user principal you will be accessing the session.

Comment: @Nkosi Is that code could work on aspnet Mvc that is not dotnetcore? Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA that code is not core and it can work with MVC

Comment: @vasily.sib yes you did.